# Dgraph regex query with variables when using Dgraph Go client QueryWithVars

Tags: regex, variables, go, dgraph

Is it possible to use variables with regex search when using the Dgraph go client?

We could built the query with SprintF but that would be insecure.

```
q :=query Search($searchterm: string) {
        subdomains(func: regexp(name, /^.*$searchterm/)) {
        uid:uid
        name:name
    }
}
```

The following query does not return any results, even tho they exist.

```
q := `query Search($searchterm: string) {
        subdomains(func: regexp(name, /$searchterm/)) {
            uid:uid
            name:name
        }
    }`
```

Or this

```
q := `query Search($searchterm: string) {
        subdomains(func: regexp(name, /.*$searchterm.*/)) {
            uid:uid
            name:name
        }
    }`
```

Then send the query to dgraph using: txn.QueryWithVars(ctx, q, variableMap)

Edit: This is a bug.

Comment: Nothing about your sample code is valid. Try starting with code that compiles.

Comment: That is part of a dgraph query made using the Go client. It compiles.

Comment: No, it does not compile. It's nothing like valid Go. [See here](https://play.golang.org/p/zIYxcejFufP).

Comment: Dgraph developers have fixed the issue. https://github.com/dgraph-io/dgraph/pull/2353

Answer (score 0):

Not the way you're doing it. But you can build a dynamic regex pattern by joining strings the normal way:

```
re, err := regexp.Compile("ˆ.*" + regexp.QuoteMeta(searchTerm))
```